# General Purpose Antonym for "Ago"

Tags: antonyms

I'm refactoring a function I had to show relative dates like StackExchange does, eg.:

> *relative unit of time* (second/minute/hour/day/week/month/year)[s]
>   (ago/from now)

However, I started wondering if the expression "from now" is the most logical / appropriate for general purpose futuristic use - perhaps "to go" (this kind of makes me imagine a space shuttle launch...) or some other expression would be a better choice?

Comment: "5 years ago, I did this" = OK. "5 years from now, I will do this" = OK. "5 years to go, I will do this" = bad.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Great exemplification, +1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"From now" makes sense for the purpose you're suggesting, but if you're after a single word I think "[hence](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hence)" carries the same meaning.

Comment: My only quibble with @Jon Purdy is that I was just about to post "*Hence* is right on the money". But it took too long to enter - unsurprisingly, given that I *am* the archetypal slow typist.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Huh. So that's what the name's about, then?

Comment: @Andy: You're right - "hence" carries the same meaning, but using the example @Kosmonaut gave: "5 years hence, I will do this" sounds wrong to me (however I'm not a native English speaker and I don't use the word hence that often) - is it just me?

Comment: 'hence', though it does save space, is a bit too formal sounding and on its way to being archaic.

Comment: @Alix: "5 years hence, I will do this" sounds perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @Mitch: You don't think we'll be using "hence" fifty years hence?

Comment: @Andy F: No, I don't think anyone outside of academia will... That was my snap judgement, but then I checked [Google Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=hence%2Cthence%2Cwhence&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). I love that thing even though the data is questionable...if the picture is right, you can cherry pick the ones in your favor for an argument! I also don't think anybody will be using the subjunctive or 'shall' either.

Comment: ...which is to say that "hence" is exactly right if one word is sought, but I feel "from now" sounds more natural. I had already plus-oned this, but just wanted to give a little extra perspective.

Comment: @Mitch: And for the record, I agree completely. Hence doesn't really have the natural ring to it that "from now" does.

Comment: Funny to see google translation english->french `two hours hence->dans deux heures` is OK but `two minutes hence->deux minutes d'où` `two seconds hence->deux secondes donc` `two decades hence->deux décennies à l'` `two centuries hence->deux siècles où` `two days hence->deux jours`

Answer (score 5):

If you are setting the labels for a time machine, both clarity and brevity would be nice. "Ago" is the clearest shortest label for anything in the past, and "ahead" is my preference over "from now".

Side note: Ago comes from the Old English *agone*, meaning "departed, passed away", as in gone.

Comment: Though, I do like that "from now" contains an explicit reference to a particular point in time to start from (now), whereas this is just implied in "ahead".

Comment: So ahead would be the antonym of late rather than ago? (my product came two years ahead, two years late)